# Hide password in Yii2 in model when user request information

Tags: yii2

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-models.md#fields-

I've read this article but can't understand how it works. I wrote it in my code, but with no luck. 
In model class fields like this:

```
public function fields() {
    $fields = parent::fields();

    // remove fields that contain sensitive information
    unset($fields['password']);

    return $fields;
}
```

For example I want return information about one user:

```
$account = Account::findOne($id);
return Json::encode(['error' => 0, 'message' => '', 'data' => $account]);
```

And when I want return a bunch of users:

```
$accounts = Account::find()->where(['companyId' => $companyId])->orderBy('username')->asArray()->all();
return Json::encode(['error' => 0, 'message' => 'Users in company', 'data' => $accounts]);
```

So how to hide fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is correct and it will hide the password field**

**If u want another way u can select the fields you want to show like this:**

```
$accounts = Account::find()
    ->select(['field1','field2'])
    ->where(['companyId' => $companyId])->orderBy('username')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
return Json::encode(['error' => 0, 'message' => 'Users in company', 'data' => $accounts]);
```

Comment: your code woking well, but my code in question is not hiding

Comment: well! @kazux you are right. For those who did same mistake, pay attention that you don't use '$account->attributes' because in this case you will take all fields from database whatever you wrote in fields method.

Answer (score 0):

Its Pretty Simple:

Just try 
`$account->fields();`

Comment: @Junaith Any Justification ?